# $rootScope variable is undefined inside directive

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('microFrontEnd', function($rootScope) {
   'use strict';       
    $rootScope.show = true;
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '../template.html'
    };
});
```

and the template:

```
<div ng-show="$rootScope.show">Hello man</div>
```

Why `$rootScope.show` is undefined? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is replacing `$rootScope.show`with `$root.show`. Any explanation about that?